# Is there a way to use flags when searching with hoogle from ghci?

Tags: haskell, ghci, hoogle

How can I use the hoogle command line flags when using hoogle inside ghci?

This obviously doesn't work:

```
ghci> :hoogle --count=5 Char -> Int
Could not read as type Int, "5 Char -> Int"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to change your ghci.conf in order to do this. Assuming you did the [steps described on haskell.org](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Hoogle#Hoogle_Integration_Modes), your ghci.conf contains a line like

```
:def hoogle \x -> return $ ":!hoogle \"" ++ x ++ "\""
```

However, that line says that `:hoogle x` will be translated to `hoogle "x"`, which obviously won't work if you want to apply additional flags, such as `--count=5`.

You either need to remove the quotes around the argument, e.g.

```
:def hoogleP \x -> return $ ":!hoogle " ++ x
```

and use `:hoogleP --count=5 "Char -> Int"` or split the argument by hand into count and search query:

```
:def hoogleC \x -> return $ ":!hoogle --count="++(head.words $x)++" \"" ++ (unwords.tail.words $x) ++ "\""
```

The last version can be used as `:hoogleC 5 Char -> Int`.

Comment: If hoogleC would employ `unwords` instead of `concat`, this wouldn't happen:`ghci> :hoogleC 1 Maybe a -> a
Warning: Unknown type Maybea
Unsafe.Coerce unsafeCoerce :: a -> b`

Comment: Thanks for writing your answer and updating it! It's super useful!